# Unable to execute a file from second hard disk in Ubuntu

Tags: folder-permissions, mounted-volumes

My computer has two hard disks (1 SSD + 1 HDD). I have installed operating systems in SSD and made HDD as a NTFS drive (named as 'WorkData'; and the location is `/media/WorkData`), so that I can work in that HDD from both Ubuntu and Windows.

I have compiled a program (named as 'chem') in 'WorkData' and tried executing it by `./chem` command. However, I am getting the error 'bash: ./chem: Permission denied'.

I tried following ways to fix it:

1) Used, `chmod u+x chem` => No use.
2) Tried the option in the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/99635/cant-execute-a-script-on-a-mounted-external-drive) => No use.
3) Tried the option in the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49392/how-to-mark-allow-executing-file-as-program-on-an-external-drive) => No use.

Can some one help me in this regard?

Thanks,
Rveera

Comment: You might be better off asking this on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).